# async function arguments becomes "undefined" in iOS Chrome, but works on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, undefined

I have this code. It works fine in Android Chrome. In iOS resp shows "undefined".

```
async function submitfuncR(resp,saveterminal){
   alert(resp);   THIS SHOW "UNDEFINED"
   ............
}


async function submitfunc(submitfuncR) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status ===200 ) {
         ...........
        resp=xhr.response;
        submitfuncR(resp,saveterminal);
      }
    }
    xhr.open("POST",_serverpar,true);
    xhr.send("login;");
    return false;
}
```

It is called in the  section like this:
"    Enviar"

Comment: I am unable to pt this in the post. It is called in the body section like this: <button class ="nobutton" type="button" id ="sendcode" style="margin-top:-4px;font-size: 3.9vh; display:inline-block;" onclick="submitfunc(submitfuncR)">Enviar</button>